# How to retrieve the value of a checkboxlist? I added the value using array c#

Tags: c#, checkboxlist

I am working on a solar system calculator. I added some of the items to the checkboxlist using an array for example: checkboxlist item 1 contains "Led Tv: 1 for 1 hour/day, 25 watt each". see code below.

```
public addValues()
        {
            string[] values = new string[] { metroComboBox1.Text + " : " + textBox2.Text + " for " + textBox3.Text + " hours/day  " + " @ " + textBox1.Text + " watts each " };
            itemList.Items.AddRange(values);
        }
```

On button click, I called the method

```
private void itemAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            addValues();
            Double aa, bb, aba, cc, dd, ee;
            aa = Double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            bb = Double.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            aba = Double.Parse(textBox3.Text);

            if(totalPower.Text == "0")
            {
                cc = aa * bb;
                totalPower.Text = cc.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                cc = aa * bb;
                dd = Double.Parse(totalPower.Text);
                ee = cc + dd;
                totalPower.Text = ee.ToString();
            }
        }
```

I removed checked items from the list using this code.

```
private void itemRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var item in itemList.CheckedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray())
                {
                    itemList.Items.Remove(item);
                }
        }
```

The issue here is how to automatically reduce the value of the totalPower.Text whenever I remove an item from the list? Please I will be glad if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the issue you are facing is that you have lost the information of each item you added, as it's calculated only as string.

I would suggest to look it at a different angle. You should model your real-world problem in your code. Let's say that you have a class for your items in the list, with multiple properties. 
For example:

```
public class ConsumptionItem {
 public string Description {get; set;}
 public double Count {get; set;}
 public double HoursPerDay {get; set;}
 public double Watts {get; set;}

 public string Label 
 { 
   get {return "What you want to appear in your list. You can use any property here, like " + HoursPerDay + " hours.";
 }
}
```

Then, in your CheckBoxList, you can specify to show the Label property from your class. Refer to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.displaymember?view=netframework-4.8) to see how this works.

This way, you will have a clearer model of the problem and you can use each item in your calculations.

A few suggestions:

1. Please use descriptive names for your variables. Trying to figure out what aa, ab, ac, aac etc. refers to can be a pain and wastes your time.
2. Each time you add an item, you make a call to `addValues()` and you add the same item each time to the list. Are you sure you want to do just that?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. However, the variables "aa, bb, aba" are variable I used to get values from 3 text boxes. When multiplied it gives me the TotalPower consumed. ie      
      cc = aa * bb; totalPower.Text = cc.ToString();

Comment: Still, a clearer set of variables will save you a lot of time. For example aa should be watts, bb amperes and cc volts (if i understand correctly what you are trying to accomplish). Anyway, that was the extra part of my answer. Please leave feedback if my solution/advice solved your problem

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was able to resolve this by using a different control ListViewItem